# Using thymeleaf to display an error message alters the layout of my login form

Tags: html, css, authentication, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf to display an error message on my Login form upon entering wrong credentials:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form class="form" id="login" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
      <h1 class="form__title">Login</h1>
      <div th:if="${param.error}" class="form__message form__message-error">
        invalid username or password
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Since this error-message div only appears upon entering wrong credentials, my form changes its layout - the input fields are moving downwards. I don't want this. I want the form to look the same in either way, only the message is supposed to get written or deleted. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`th:if` will only add the `<div>` when the `error` request parameter is there. To do what you want, you should use CSS to either have an empty div or show some text, using `th:classappend` to select the CSS class to use.

Something like:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form class="form" id="login" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
      <h1 class="form__title">Login</h1>
      <div th:classappend="${param.error}?'show':'hide'" class="form__message form__message-error">
        invalid username or password
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

With `.show` and `.hide` classes defined in your CSS.

Comment: this seems to be just what I am looking for! ... when I add this div block though, I am running into a TemplateProcessingException: 
`<div th:classappend="${param.error ? 'form--hidden' : 'form--shown'}" class="form__message form__message-error"> invalid username or password </div>` ... and in my css file `form--hidden` just says `display: none` and `form-shown` says `display:block`

Comment: There was a typo, fixed now in my answer. Should be `${param.error} ? 'form--hidden' : 'form--shown'` in your case.

Comment: ah, thanks a lot Wim! Now it's working. Only, the form still changes its size. But I guess it probably has something to do with my css. It's strange though I was thinking the div was still there, even if display = none.

Comment: Use `visibility:hidden` instead

Comment: perfect, thank you so much!